# When running PJSIP stack on Windows, occurs "sound_port.c !EC suspended because of inactivity"

Tags: windows-7, pjsip

I’m running **PJSIP** on Win7. The problem is that I can register successfully and when I make call, the call can established, but I can't hear voice.

A problem occurs:

> sound_port.c !EC suspended because of inactivity"

I captures the packets, I don't find any RTP packets on receiving.

Answer (score 2):

As you mention there are no RTP packets you would hear nothing.

*`sound_port.c !EC suspended because of inactivity`* message is telling you the same thing.

Check why you are not receiving RTP. Does far end send RTP..? A few likely problems - 
 NAT'ting / SDP details (ip address, codecs mismatch)